# Custom renderer and lights in Threejs for wireless raytracing?

Tags: three.js, physics, raytracing

I have been using Three.js for a couple of weeks now and am really blown away by the power of this library!

Now, I would like to leverage it in order to run raytracing simulations for lower frequencies than light (RF). I figure it should be possible to alter or create new lights that would represent the sources of RF waves and then write a specific renderer that would take into account the interference aspects that apply in the RF context.

Is that the right approach? If so what functions/libraries should I focus on? Maybe all the raytracing/raycasting is already done and can be reused with little modification?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes depending on what domain you are modelling, radiometric simulations can be done with ray tracing. Photometric renderers are Radiometric renderers but with the domain restricted to the visible spectrum. Usually you can simply replace words like 'Lux' with 'Flux' which can give the indication that the domain being modelled can be outside the visible spectrum.

Bear in mind, depending on what you wish model, you need to assume that the RF waves will behave in a similar vein to a ray/photon. i.e Diffraction or movement through vector fields will require intelligence beyond standard **path tracing**, instead look at **ray marching** used in volumetric renderers. Volumetric ray tracing is more akin to finite element analysis since we don't just calculate the intersection point of the ray, but also consider the ray propagation through a medium (vector field) and the effect this medium has on the resultant ray path.

P.S Sorry can't help with specifics of Threejs :( Never used it.